# Tomcat 9.0.16 + Java11 sometimes produces "Error parsing HTTP request header"

Tags: ssl, https, java-11, jsse, tomcat9

We have webapp running in Tomcat 9.0.16, after change AdoptJDK from 10 to 11 we have noticed once in a while HTTP 400 status in access log. This is happening only, if HTTPS is configured, we are using Java SSL implementation (JSSE).
Below is dump from javax.net.debug of the failed request.

Difference from other request is that there is change_cipher_spec after application_data in same thread. I have not noticed this sequence in passed requests.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|38|https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5|2019-03-01 14:01:46.924 CET|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:177|Raw read (
  0000: 17 03 03 02 CE 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 01 06 11 6D  ...............m
  0010: 72 C0 DE E5 55 76 24 8D   18 F3 13 69 43 2A AA 84  r...Uv$....iC*..
  0020: 37 01 CE 8F 16 C9 72 E9   52 5D 43 BA 96 C7 47 8B  7.....r.R]C...G.
  0030: 86 7A 6C C8 A0 72 E0 38   3A FF 54 83 C3 60 8D 6F  .zl..r.8:.T..`.o
  0040: 2A 56 E6 E0 A2 B8 1E 6C   1E 5E 8A 9B 3C 7F A3 34  *V.....l.^..<..4
  0050: 56 86 09 69 4B E8 E1 22   45 88 B4 E7 DC C0 0A B7  V..iK.."E.......
  0060: 91 2A 6E 1C A9 28 4B 37   96 72 4E 94 01 E9 A1 64  .*n..(K7.rN....d
  0070: 67 F1 6E BC 9C 34 69 E3   92 35 DC F2 45 5F B6 EB  g.n..4i..5..E_..
  0080: 58 82 C0 9B 86 A1 15 2F   0B FC E8 6E 97 18 30 34  X....../...n..04
  0090: B2 DA FA 55 0E 4F 92 AD   5A B9 6C 46 C8 22 FD 33  ...U.O..Z.lF.".3
  00A0: 12 8F 71 8F D8 08 EB E8   BC 55 67 1D 23 8E A7 89  ..q......Ug.#...
  00B0: BF 22 63 89 FE B5 B5 DA   DF 26 54 B8 5C 53 99 79  ."c......&T.\S.y
  00C0: 84 B8 04 70 A9 DB FF 54   91 59 B7 8F 06 39 6E 17  ...p...T.Y...9n.
  00D0: 2A C6 A1 20 30 AF 67 F1   1C 1E B0 E8 A4 29 66 CA  *.. 0.g......)f.
  00E0: 95 B1 94 AE 6F EC 53 98   60 EF E9 06 CD 05 F6 04  ....o.S.`.......
  00F0: 06 27 30 96 3F 8B F0 76   6B 92 1C B7 89 5C 47 9A  .'0.?..vk....\G.
  0100: C6 A5 44 2D 2A DB B6 EC   E2 BC 56 57 0C 9B 6A FB  ..D-*.....VW..j.
  0110: 5B 64 F4 56 27 41 B8 74   69 4B 46 47 B0 8A 25 EE  [d.V'A.tiKFG..%.
  0120: 57 81 A0 D5 C2 F5 2D E9   3B C1 C8 A1 05 5B 25 DF  W.....-.;....[%.
  0130: BA 96 B1 5A 59 E6 A9 A4   94 2D 86 CF BF 4C 4E 70  ...ZY....-...LNp
  0140: 68 EB 78 4E 3A 39 AC 56   3E 24 C2 1A 21 DC C1 BD  h.xN:9.V>$..!...
  0150: D7 0C 51 2B 99 C6 49 40   25 30 16 B5 2E AB 8F CC  ..Q+..I@%0......
  0160: D4 DA 9F 7A 50 F5 B7 28   55 32 B1 44 CE 89 8A 5F  ...zP..(U2.D..._
  0170: 79 89 34 E2 F0 A1 A3 56   15 7A 15 B7 EA 4C 74 8D  y.4....V.z...Lt.
  0180: 87 F2 2B 81 DB 4B 86 99   01 4C AC 5C 05 42 20 C8  ..+..K...L.\.B .
  0190: 50 DA AA D6 BF 36 BC 78   67 DA CB 57 CD 7E 3B A8  P....6.xg..W..;.
  01A0: 53 66 06 72 43 EA C2 F6   DA 2B 99 50 83 A6 C3 72  Sf.rC....+.P...r
  01B0: BB 6F 05 7F 60 B1 25 07   93 61 71 2C 25 12 B9 90  .o..`.%..aq,%...
  01C0: DC 42 F2 72 9E 38 85 60   61 58 44 3A 03 C4 0E 9E  .B.r.8.`aXD:....
  01D0: 1A 60 9B F3 D4 8C 66 9C   5D 01 86 E5 21 D2 F3 40  .`....f.]...!..@
  01E0: D8 52 DF 76 D4 C6 67 B0   29 C5 56 9B A2 05 8C 8D  .R.v..g.).V.....
  01F0: BE 58 59 06 2B 1C F4 A7   6B 6B 40 67 04 E1 ED B2  .XY.+...kk@g....
  0200: 18 C0 F4 43 00 1F EC 68   7C F2 C1 10 01 62 74 C2  ...C...h.....bt.
  0210: 62 5F 4B 19 48 27 A8 57   99 8A 74 81 D2 33 F3 FC  b_K.H'.W..t..3..
  0220: 5C 29 05 5A 44 BA 9E 4C   DD 4C EA 50 D2 6E 95 E9  \).ZD..L.L.P.n..
  0230: 7C AF A0 FE 6F EB 31 4C   8D 44 97 61 16 46 B2 B4  ....o.1L.D.a.F..
  0240: D4 F4 84 8C 9E 20 D3 67   97 BE 8A 31 7E 67 A1 BC  ..... .g...1.g..
  0250: B5 C8 0A 83 B3 47 C0 2A   A2 51 73 C8 D2 F3 6B FF  .....G.*.Qs...k.
  0260: D8 95 BC 5E BA AE EA 3A   2A 9E F7 AD DA AC 90 B9  ...^...:*.......
  0270: C1 34 4E F2 4D 61 95 C2   D6 BF 3D A1 81 13 83 8F  .4N.Ma....=.....
  0280: D9 FB CC 7B 83 DA 4D 53   AE B2 C5 86 1A 3F 25 4B  ......MS.....?%K
  0290: 0D BA EA 32 1D 08 B3 8B   8B AD 8B EF EA 47 2F A6  ...2.........G/.
  02A0: 41 AF 38 F5 15 52 84 2C   41 9E 77 DE ED 8D A5 9A  A.8..R.,A.w.....
  02B0: A6 5A 1A C9 0B 87 C4 6E   2A 34 CC 7A 91 5A 1E DF  .Z.....n*4.z.Z..
  02C0: E9 58 BB 3A B8 8A E2 0F   9F 0F DE 5C F6 55 B3 1B  .X.:.......\.U..
  02D0: 4A 73 02 14 03 03 00 01   01 16 03 03 00 28 00 00  Js...........(..
  02E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 94 1E   F8 9A 66 3B A1 67 AB 89  ..........f;.g..
  02F0: 39 DB 30 3E 90 11 45 92   1C EA 7F F7 91 D8 8B 9E  9.0>..E.........
  0300: B6 58 CC 9F 19 AD                                  .X....
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|38|https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5|2019-03-01 14:01:46.924 CET|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 718
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|38|https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5|2019-03-01 14:01:46.924 CET|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:177|Raw read (
  0000: 14 03 03 00 01 01 16 03   03 00 28 00 00 00 00 00  ..........(.....
  0010: 00 00 00 94 1E F8 9A 66   3B A1 67 AB 89 39 DB 30  .......f;.g..9.0
  0020: 3E 90 11 45 92 1C EA 7F   F7 91 D8 8B 9E B6 58 CC  >..E..........X.
  0030: 9F 19 AD                                           ...
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|38|https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5|2019-03-01 14:01:46.925 CET|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 change_cipher_spec, length = 1
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|38|https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5|2019-03-01 14:01:46.925 CET|ChangeCipherSpec.java:143|Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|38|https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5|2019-03-01 14:01:46.925 CET|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:177|Raw read (
  0000: 16 03 03 00 28 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 94 1E F8  ....(...........
  0010: 9A 66 3B A1 67 AB 89 39   DB 30 3E 90 11 45 92 1C  .f;.g..9.0>..E..
  0020: EA 7F F7 91 D8 8B 9E B6   58 CC 9F 19 AD           ........X....
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|38|https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5|2019-03-01 14:01:46.925 CET|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 40
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|38|https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5|2019-03-01 14:01:46.925 CET|SSLCipher.java:1629|Plaintext after DECRYPTION (
  0000: 14 00 00 0C D4 93 7A FD   9E 7D 6A F2 04 97 1A 93  ......z...j.....
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|38|https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5|2019-03-01 14:01:46.925 CET|Finished.java:581|Consuming client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: D4 93 7A FD 9E 7D 6A F2   04 97 1A 93 
  }'}
)
01-Mar-2019 14:01:46.927 INFO [https-jsse-nio-8444-exec-5] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: According to the stacktrace the problem is a malformed HTTP header. This has nothing to do with the TLS handshake (which was successfully finished) and debugging on this level is no use. One would need to see the relevant HTTP header (TLS decrypted) instead. Also, can you reproduce the problem or can you pin down it to a specific client or is the server just on the internet where arbitrary clients will connect and try how your system reacts to invalid input.